# How to run multiple queries in Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I tried by selecting all the queries and pressing Ctrl + Enter (It didn't worked)
I also tried Ctrl + Shift + Enter (It didn't worked)

```
select* From user;
Select * from doctor;
Select * from problems;
```

Comment: Press the Lightening icon ( the one without the cursor symbol in front of it)

Comment: But you will still only see the result of the second query in the output area

Comment: What does "_It didn't work[ed]_" mean? What _does_ happen? What did you expect to happen? Usually when you execute multiple queries, Workbench will show multiple tabs in the result. Did you notice those tabs?

Comment: This looks like you normally work in another IDE and expect the same commands to work in the same way in workbench

Answer (score 0):

```
Ctrl + Shift + Enter
```

shortcut give you multiple query result

[image]

and you switch the tab I attached image above

Comment: I tried this and it was not working.

Comment: @Anushka I did same and its working fine !

Comment: You can also select all the three queries and press on the flash button that will also work.

Comment: @Anushka I already knew this but I thought you need to shortcut btw thanks!